# Медиафайлы Strapi не отображаются в панели администратора

Tags: strapi

Я работаю над проектом Strapi, который я разрабатываю на нескольких компьютерах. Для удобства соответственно использую Git и Github.

Папка public/uploads загружается в репозиторий Github вместе со всем ее содержимым.

Чтобы загрузить изменения, использую команду git pull.

Все медиафайлы загружены в одноименную папку, но они не отображаются в административной панели, поле изображения также пусто в созданных мной ресурсах.

Как решить эту проблему? В продакшене я собираюсь хранить файлы так же в этой папке, без облачных сервисов.

[image: Медиа библиотека в административной панели]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что в репозиторий не попадала БД data.db  из папки .tmp. После правки файла .gitignore все стало как нужно.

Comment: База данных в принципе не должна храниться в git репозитории.